# Trying to run JUnit test but getting an ERROR: Implementing class

Tags: testing, junit, persistence, entity

I'm trying to run a simple test with following class (DataStructureTest) code:

```
public class DataStructureTest extends DatabaseTestCase {

private static final Log log = (Log) LogFactory.getLog(DataStructureTest.class);

@Test
public void testProductData(){
    //Creating a product data
    log.debug("Creating new product data");
    ProductData productData = new ProductData("Öljy");

    //Setting basic information of product
    log.debug("Setting basic information like name, price, description "
            + "and amount.");
    productData.setProductPrice(4.13);
    productData.setProductDescription("Öljy rekoille.");
    productData.setProductAmount(20);

    //Saving entity
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    em.persist(productData);
    Integer primarykey = productData.getId();
    tx.commit();

    //Reading entity from database
    log.debug("Reading entity data from database.");
    tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    productData = em.find(ProductData.class, primarykey);
    tx.commit();   

    //Asserting that the product data was correct in database
    Assert.assertEquals("Product name was correct", "Öljy", 
            productData.getProductName());
    Assert.assertEquals("Product price was correct", 4.13, 
            productData.getProductPrice());
    Assert.assertEquals("Product description was correct", "Öljy rekoille", 
            productData.getProductDescription());
    Assert.assertEquals("Product amount was incorrect", 21, 
            productData.getProductAmount());

}
```

}

DatabaseTestCase class code is following:

```
public class DatabaseTestCase {

/**
* This method establishes Entity Managerin before every test
* and writes information into log.
*/
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DatabaseTestCase.class);
private EntityManager entityManager;
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Before
public void establishEntityManager(){
    log.debug("Establishing database connection!");
    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("warehouseTestPersistence", null);
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

@After
public void closeEntityManager(){
   if(entityManager != null){
        entityManager.close();           
   } else {
       log.warn("Entity was empty (null) in tests.");
   }
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    return entityManager;
}

/**
 * @param entityManager the entityManager to set
 */
public void setEntityManager(final EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

/**
 * @return the entityManagerFactory
 */
public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    return entityManagerFactory;
}

/**
 * @param entityManagerFactory the entityManagerFactory to set
 */
public void setEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
}

/**
* Save entity to database. Used for assisting in tests.
* @return primary key for specific entity.
*/

protected Integer saveEntity(Entityclass entity){
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    em.persist(entity);
    tx.commit();
    return entity.getId();
}

/**
 * Load entity from save location.
 * @param <T>
 *      Generic class.
 * @param entityclass
 *      Entity class of entity that is going to be loaded.
 * @param primarykey
 *      Entity class primary key.
 * @return correspondant entity.
 */
protected <T extends Entityclass> T loadEntity(final Class<T> entitysclass, final Integer primarykey){
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    T entity = em.find(entitysclass, primarykey);
    tx.commit();
    return entity;
}
```

}

I use NetBeans 7.0.1. All imports for both class are done properly. I have also added all required dependencies. But whenever I run a test I get following result:

-- error field --

No test passed, 1 test caused an error.(0,075 s)
com.mysite.warehouseapp.DataStructureTest FAILED
testProductData caused an ERROR: Implementing class

Implementing class
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at....
at com.mysite.warehouseapp.test.DatabaseTestCase.establishEntityManager(DatabaseTestCase.java:36)

-- test result field --

- Establishing database connection!
- Entity was empty (null) in tests.

if you see the test result image at top I don't know how it got there but it supposed to be in this location.

So briefly said whenever I try to run the test there's no entity. Can anybody tell me the reason? I have tried to find solution for this problem for four days but still with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any help for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution my ownself, which is quiet rewarding :). Anyway the solution for this problem was that the persistence.xml was in wrong folder. And for newbies, I would advice you to put persistence.xml under following folder in your project src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml.

If you don't have resources/META-INF folder created under src/test, then create one and place your persistence.xml file there. I hope this helps somebody :)

Another thing which I found out was that you might have different jars that are "against" each other and thus you need to take out those jars then it will work.